Flutter: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1
I am getting these errors whenever I run `flutter buid apk` for first time. After first time if I make the build again it does not happen. If I clear caches and make build again then it happens again for first time.
Commands which cause these errors again after first time build:
flutter clean
flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk
e: E:/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/760f7ca3c06fd16010ad3c3f87a73608/transformed/jetified-play-services-location-21.2.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gms.libs.identity_identity.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: E:/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: E:/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: E:/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: E:/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.9.0/cd65c21cfd1eec4d44ef09f9f52b6d9f8a720636/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
This is what I have done so far to fix it but no luck.

I have upgraded flutter and dart,

Installed fresh Android studio again.

Upgraded all package

Added dependency_overrides to latest dependencies versions.


Following is my file structure:
pubspec.yaml
name: example_app
description: app description

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 0.0.1+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  cmp_sdk: ^0.1.0
  compute: ^1.0.2
  connectivity_plus: ^6.0.3
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  firebase_analytics: ^10.10.6
  firebase_core: ^2.31.1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.9.3
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.5
  flutter_breadcrumb: ^1.0.1
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.15.0
  http: ^1.2.1
  image_picker: ^1.1.1
  intl: any
  location: ^6.0.2
  path: any
  provider: ^6.1.2
  share_plus: ^9.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  transparent_image: ^2.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.2.6
  youtube_player_iframe: ^5.1.2

dependency_overrides:
  js: ^0.7.1
  leak_tracker: ^10.0.5
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing: ^3.0.5
  material_color_utilities: ^0.11.1
  meta: ^1.15.0
  package_info_plus: ^8.0.0
  test_api: ^0.7.1
  vm_service: ^14.2.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

flutter:
  generate: true
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - lib/.env

android/build.gradle:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android/app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.exmaple.application_1"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    // kotlin {
    //     jvmToolchain(11)
    // }

    // buildFeatures {
    //     compose true
    // }
    
    // composeOptions {
    //     kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.2'
    // }
    
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.application_1
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion = 21 //flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.9.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.99'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1'
    implementation 'net.consentmanager.sdk:android:2.4.0'
}

android\settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.0.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.13" apply false
}

include ":app"

android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip

I have already many solutions other related question and articles but none of them has helped so far.
Does anyone have any idea what I could be missing or doing wrong here?

Can you check your kotlin version in cmd and tell me what it is. I was also facing same prblm but that only show in local device when building app but when building the same with codemagic do not gave these warnings

Did you find any solution?

I've found that this issue happens when you have location based packages in your app, not sure why, but this is how I fixed it.
In android>build.gradle add this line to your buildscript
change 2.0.0 to latest version if it isn't anymore
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0'

so the top of the file should look something like this
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0'
    
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'  // Use the latest version available
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'  // Use the latest version available
    }
}

In settings.gradle you have a plugins section. You need to change the kotlin version there too
So this line
 id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false

Should be changed to
 id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false

The 2.0.0 should match the kotlin_version above

I spent all day reading different forums and trying to find a solution.
Your answer is the only one that helped me. Thanks!

Thanks so much, this was exactly what I needed to make my Flutter app compile again. I am indeed using location based packages.

Try replacing this line in android/app/build.gradle:
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.9.0"


With:
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.1"


Thank you for your response, I tried your solution but it didn't work. Still getting some errors on first build.

Also, downgrading can only be a temporary fix at best. The answer should explain how this can be solved permanently.
